# Custom component receives boolean variable but does not update NgIf in HTML

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4, angular-components, angular-ng-if

I have a custom component that has an *ngIf in its view and receives a boolean variable, but *ngIf doesn't work. This is the code:

**Component**

```
@Input('title') titleText;
@Input('backButton') backButton;
@Input('avatarImage') avatarImage;
@Input('userId') userId;
@Output('avatarClicked') avatarClicked = new EventEmitter()

titlePage: string;
img: string; 
back: boolean = false;

constructor() {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.titlePage = this.titleText;
    this.img = this.avatarImage;    
    this.back = this.backButton;    
}

openPersonalData() {
    this.avatarClicked.emit({value: this.userId})
}
```

**Component HTML**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>        
        <ion-buttons *ngIf="back == true" slot="start">
            <ion-back-button text="Voltar"></ion-back-button>
        </ion-buttons>
        <ion-title>{{ titlePage }}</ion-title>        
        <ion-avatar slot="end" (click)="openPersonalData()">
            <img [src]="img">
        </ion-avatar>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

**Page using the component**

```
<app-header title="Chat" 
    [backButton]="true" 
    avatarImage="{{ user[0].img }}" 
    userId="{{ user[0].id }}" 
    (avatarClicked)="openPersonalData($event)">
</app-header>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code below works right, with the logic you need:

**You can check it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-bash-c33rc?file=/src/app/app.component.html):** (you only need to change the value of [backButton]="true" to [backButton]="false" to see it showing/not showing the son)

FATHER HTML:

```
<app-header
  title="If you see this, backButton is set to true"
  [backButton]="true"
>
</app-header>
```

SON HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="backButton">
  {{ title }}
</div>
```

SON COMPONENT TS:

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-header",
  templateUrl: "./header.component.html",
  styleUrls: []
})
export class HeaderComponent {
  @Input("title") title;
  @Input("backButton") backButton;
}
```

Comment: I tested your solution with both ionic serve and ionic lab but it didn't work...

Comment: So,  the problem is not the communication between both components by the @input boolenv variable. It's something related with the ionics components, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that wasn't the problem. I recently updated ionic cli and node in my project. It must have given some incompatibility. I created a new project from scratch and now it works. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think your input is being set after the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook. Also it's a bit redundant to reassign a field. You can simply use the `backButton` input in your template.

```html
<ion-buttons *ngIf="backButton == true" slot="start">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I've tried assigning values ​​to inputs inside an ngOnInit and inside the constructor too, but to no avail.
The problem is not just the Back button, but also other elements that vary in the header from page to page.
The important thing is to find out what I'm doing wrong for ngif to work.

Comment: You shouldn't assign values to the inputs anywhere. They should only come from the parent component and that's it. You also shouldn't create duplicate fields to use them. My solution also doesn't work then?

Comment: Okay, I removed the assignments and used the variable in the html the way I define it in the input *ngIf="backButton == true", but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should affect your data values in the `ngOnchnages` lifecycle method :

// Runs whenever component @Inputs change

```
@Input('title') titleText;
@Input('backButton') backButton: boolean;
@Input('avatarImage') avatarImage;
@Input('userId') userId;
@Output('avatarClicked') avatarClicked = new EventEmitter()

titlePage: string;
img: string; 
back: boolean = false;

constructor() 




   ngOnChanges () {
        // Check if the data exists before using it
        if (this.backButton) {
             this.back = this.backButton; 
        {
    }
```